# Twilio are not delivering SMS to Colombia

Tags: twilio

in my solution are delivered sms to several countries via Twilio, including Colombia (+57).
Although in the Twilio console the message status is delivered, the message is never delivered.
The solution I see in Twilio documentation, it to buy a number of the country. But when I try to do that, i see a warning message that Colombia (+57) does not have SMS capability.

So, What I can do? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Ask the vendor’s customer support what’s going on.

Comment: the vendor always sent me to their documentation, where there is nothing about it.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. This is absolutely something our support team should be able to help you with. If they have sent you to the docs, I'm sorry about that. Can you please try to open a new support ticket with specific message SIDs that display as "delivered" but never arrived, so that we can follow up with the carrier? Thanks, and let me know if you have any additional questions or issues.